# Find a point $Q$ in the $3$-dimensional space such that the points $(0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 2, 3)$, $(2, 2, −2)$, and $Q$ form a rectangle

Tags: linear-algebra

I was hoping for some guidance after finding out that
$$x=-2y-3z+14$$
from the orthogonality criterion.

Comment: You search a point $Q$ or $R$ ?

Comment: What is $R$ is your title ?

Comment: change r to q sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy because $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,2,-2)$ are orthogonal to each other.
You can see that the scalar product of the vectors pointing from the origin to the given two points are zero: 
$$(1,2,3)\cdot(2,2,-2)=2+4-6=0$$

Then simple $$Q=(1,2,3)+(2,2,-2)=(3,4,1)$$
is the point opposite to the origin ($(0,0,0)$).

Because of the fact that the point $Q$ is a linear combination of the other points: All points are in one plane. (Spanned by $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,2,-2)$ going through the origin $(0,0,0)$)

Looking at the distances between the points you see that you have a Parallelogramm.

And because of beeing one angle $90°$ you have a rectangle.

Comment: You answered the question perfectly except i could understand the grammar, could you rephrase what you said algebraically?

Comment: The "see their scalar product" and "you Q is linear combination of the other points"

Comment: yes thank you very much :)